# Python Sqlite3 Not Selecting most up-to-date database

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working on a user login form in python (just as practice) and I am linking it to an Sqlite3 database.  I have set it up so I can validate users without a problem, and am now trying to implement a way to add users.  My function to add users looks like this

```
def add_user();
    usernameTaken = True
        db.execute("SELECT username from users")
        currentUsers = set(db.fetchone())
        print(currentUsers)
        while usernameTaken:
            user = input("Choose a username: ")
            if user in currentUsers:
                print("Username taken please try again")
            else: usernameTaken = False
        pswd = input("Choose a Password: ")     # prompt user for username and password
        salt, key = hash(pswd)                  # hash pswd to get user-specific salt and hash
        values = user, salt, key
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (user, salt, key))
        print(db.fetchone())
        conn.commit()
        return
```

This for the most part works, it ensures I can't repeat usernames, and the INSERT statement inserts the correct values to the table.  However, when I run the code again, and SELECT I see the database from before I made that change.  I think that the database is updating because I can see the usernames added when I select from the database through the terminal.
P.S.
I apologize if this is a bad post, it's my first post and I couldn't find a problem similar to this anywhere

Comment: Is this in Django? Did you migrate your updated models?

Comment: It's not in Django, it's all offline just for practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `currentUsers = set(db.fetchone())` is only fetching one row. So that is all
`print(currentUsers)` shows. Perhaps have a look at [`fetchall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall)